# SSHPASS Not Passing Password to SUDO Command

Tags: ssh, sudo, sshpass

I have the below command and I'm unable to get it to run. It's saying that no password is being supplied for the SUDO command, any idea or help greatly appreciated, I've read every post I can find but to no avail.

```
sshpass -p $PASSWD ssh client_user@192.169.0.178 'cd /tmp/;echo $PASSWD | sudo -S mkdir ./test/;'
```

Also tried the below with no luck:

```
sshpass -p $PASSWD ssh client_user@192.169.0.178 <<EOF
    cd /tmp/;
    echo $PASSWD | sudo -S mkdir ./test/;
EOF
```

Error:

```
sudo: no password was provided
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact error message that you're getting. Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: @Kenster updated with the error message

Comment: on the remote side you did not set `$PASSWD` so it's empty and sudo complains.

Comment: @pynexj would this need to be set on the remote host manually or is there a way for me to pass the value for $PASSWD to the remote host for the command?